Compilation error in CRTP non-copyable hierarchy when instanting object with brace initialiser
I have the designed a CRTP-based hierarchy of classes.
In doing that, I applied the suggestion presented in this blog post and declared a) the constructor private and b) the derived class as friend.
Also, I would like the hierarchy to be non copyable, so I inherited from boost::noncopyable privately, as suggested in the online documentation. To make it easier to run the code, I will replicate is implementation here in a custom class:
struct NonCopyable {
protected:
    NonCopyable() = default;
    ~NonCopyable() = default;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};

template <class Derived>
struct Base : private NonCopyable
{
  friend Derived;
private:
  Base() = default;
};

struct MyCRTP : public Base<MyCRTP> { };

Now, I tried to instantiate a new object of class MyCRTP with the syntax MyCRTP a{};; in this case, as far as I understood, that should call the default constructor of the class.
If I try to compile this code with either g++ or clang++ using the option -std=c++17, it gives the following error:
clang++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:20:12: error: base class 'Base<MyCRTP>' has private default constructor
  MyCRTP a{};
           ^
main.cpp:14:3: note: declared private here
  Base() = default;

FULL MWE ON COLIRU
I am interested in knowing why it gives such an error, knowing that the same code builds perfectly fine if I either:

compile with -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 option;
declare the object as MyCRTP a; (as usual);
remove the inheritance from the class NonCopyable in the class Base;
inherit publicly from the class NonCopyable in the class Base;


Aggregate initialization... MyCRTP is not an aggregate before C++17 because it has a base class.

Thanks a lot for the answer. I actually found this post that explains pretty well the same issue.
